# Site crashing ie11 when dev tools closed

Tags: html, angularjs, internet-explorer

My website http://findmydoppelganger.net/ is crashing internet explorer when you don't have dev tools opened. I'm aware that in the past this may have been caused by calls to console.log but this doesn't seem to be the case here.

It's not just that the page throws an error, but it seems to actually make the whole browser hang. Does anyone have any ideas?

The site is built with angularjs if that provides any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Ok solved the problem. My application was getting stuck in an infinite loop, because IE was caching ng-resource requests (my app discards duplicates and re-tries hence the loop)  With dev tools open it doesn't do this hence the apparent bug.

Followed this guide here to force IE to not cache resource requests and all is well

http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/AngularJS-caching-issue-for-Internet-Explorer